# Error on displaying image asynchronously with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I'm building app and I need to populate a TableView with some users infos, like username and the profile picture. The following code works for downloading and displaying the image.

```
if let imageFile = usersArr[indexPath.row]["profileImage"] as? PFFile {
    let data = try? imageFile.getData()
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}
```

But this is synchronously and I want it to be asynchronously. So I tried this.

```
if let imageFile = usersArr[indexPath.row]["profileImage"] as? PFFile {
    imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
        if let imageData = data where error == nil {
            cell?.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        } else {
            cell?.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "defaultProfile")
        }     
    })
}
```

But it's not working and I can't figure out why. Not even the defaultProfile image is appearing.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the view is not being refreshed once the data has been fetched and image has been set.

I recommend using `PFImageView` from the `ParseUI` framework. It is a Parse-made image view which will automatically handle displaying a placeholder while loading, updating the data once available, and refreshing the view once the download is complete. Here's an example usage.

```
let imageView = PFImageView()

// Set placeholder image
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

// Set remote image
imageView.file = profilePicture

// Once the download completes, the remote image will be displayed
imageView.loadInBackground { (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")            
    } else {
        println("image loaded")
    }
}
```